# Extra/missing chars in scanf

Tags: c, input, scanf, getchar

this is my input function:

```
int input( int array[500][500], int *x0, int *y0 ) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int err = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    char c;
    char s[2];
    printf("Enter sizes:\n");
    if (scanf("%d %d%c", x0, y0, &c) !=3 || 
         *x0 <= 0 || *y0 <= 0 || *x0 > 500 || *y0 > 500 || c!='\n' ) {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while (y < *y0) {
        x = 0;
        temp = 0;
        while ( x < *x0 ) { 
            if ( scanf("%1s", s)==1 ) {
                c = *s;
            } // so that ooo is written into three array fields
            switch(c) { // only these three chars are accepted
            case 'o': 
                array[y][x] = 1; 
                break;
            case '.': 
                array[y][x] = 0; 
                break;
            case '!': 
                array[y][x] = 2; 
                break;
            default: 
                err = 1; 
                break;
            }
            x++;
            temp = x;
            if (temp > *x0) // my attempt
                err = 1;
        }
        if (x != *x0)
            err = 1;
        y++;
    }
    if (y != *y0)
        err = 1;
    if (err == 1) {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        return 0;
    }    
    return 1;
}
```

Basically if I input:

```
3 3
oooo
ooo
ooo
```

It should print `Invalid input.` since the second entry has 4 chars instead of 3. Similarly if I wrote 2 chars instead of three, it should also print error message.

My thinking behind the attempt is that after each read char I write that char into array (if the chars are accepted) and then `x++` so I can write the next input into the next field. So if I have 4 chars and only 3 should be accepted, `x` becomes `4` and `temp` becomes `4` too. `4 > 3` so `err=1`.

So what's wrong with my solution? What's the correct solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What part of the logic is not visible? First of I write 3 numbers, basically the size of the matrice. Then I write the matrice - only `o`, `!` or `.` are allowed. If I wrote that the matrice would be 3x3 and I input a line that has 4 chars, of course it's wrong and I need to be able to spot that mistake out.

Comment: What happens when scanf does not return 1

Comment: Then nothing. scanf would not return 1 if it wasn't a string. Even if it were a string, my switch says unless it's one of the three chars, my error flag pops up.

Comment: Are you sure? Check your logic

Comment: What's wrong with my logic? I'm reading one char at a time, I check that one char whether it is one of the three suitable chars, if yes I write into the array, if not, error flag = 1. scanf reads for a string that is 1 in length. So the only time it would not = 1 is if the input was a number. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If the scanf fails (why you are using %1s is another matter ) you carry on regardless using the previous  value of c

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assert that the user enters the characters on separate lines for each row of the matrix, use `fgets()` to read a line and parse this line by hand, skipping white space characters and handling accepted characters appropriately. Once you reach the end of your matrix row, complain if there are non space characters left in the line.

Incidentally, you should only increment `x` if the character was accepted.  In the current version, you increment `x` even when you detect an incorrect character.

Comment: By parse line by hand you mean write into a temporary array of chars and then check how many letters there were and then write that into my array?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. I've tried playing with it a bit and this is what I came up with: [code](http://pastebin.com/5qsfNnN2). This code always stops at y-2 entries despite the fact I haven't changed the `y` in the code.

Comment: In the code you refer to, `fgets()` does not have enough space to read the `'\n'` in the buffer for the first line.  The second line will be empty: you will just read the `'\n'` from the first line.  The scanning code does not stop at the `'\0'`, this `'\0'` will be considered an invalid character, setting `err=1`.  At the end of the line, you will break early from the line loop with `y` = `1` because of the test on `err`.  Make the buffer 501 bytes, stop scanning at `'\0'`, do not increment `x` on invalid or space characters.

Comment: The way I finally made it work: [function](http://pastebin.com/JhmMEgrk) and I still don't understand why I should not increment `x` on invalid characters. I mean that's what the `switch` is there for. The `default` has `err = 1` so unless the correct input was read, the flag will be up.